# Joomla: Updated module is not reading from the language file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I have made some changes to my custom module's xml manifest file and also added new entries in the module's language file but the new language entries are not translated when I edit the module.

In the language file, I added a new entry such as:

```
MOD_MY_MODULE_LABEL="This is a label"
```

When I edit the module, all I can see is `MOD_MY_MODULE_LABEL`. I've refreshed the cache for the module from the Extension Manager but it's not reading the new changes. Am I missing something?

Comment: did you placed the language file on the right path ?

Comment: If you make any changes to the module's XML file, be sure that when you are viewing the module in the Module Manager, that you click the "Save" button in the top right hand corner. Simply refreshing the page doesn't always show changes made to the XML file ;)

Comment: @Lodder Yes I did that. I wasn't just refreshing the page, I also "refreshed cache" in the Extension Manager for that particular module. My language files are INSIDE the module's folder - `mod_my_module/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_my_module.ini`.

Comment: have you checked to see if they are inside the actual Joomla's language folder too? `root/languages/en-GB/en-GB.mod_my_module.ini`

Comment: @Lodder The file is there in the root but it's not updated. I manually updated it and it's now working. I was expecting the language file in root gets updated automatically when I "refresh cache" or re-save my modules but looks like I have to manually do it.

Answer (score 1):

Once your template has been "installed", the language file in your template is no longer referenced. You need to open the following INI files:

```
/[ROOT]/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_[-=YourTemplate=-].ini
/[ROOT]/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_[-=YourTemplate=-].sys.ini
```

(Where [ROOT] is the dir you installed Joomla, and [-=YourTemplate=-] is the name you assigned your language files, they will be named exactly to the language files in your template, but in a different location for the Joomla system)

If you decide to take your template to another website (like another client) remember to grab those INIs and swap them out in your template folder

Answer (score 0):

The proper method is like follows,

In your module xml file should have language file like follows.

```
 <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_latesttweets.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_latesttweets.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
```

and your fields like.

```
<field name="consumer_key" type="text" default="" label="MOD_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY" description="MOD_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_DESC" size="60"/>
```

Then module folder have these two files.

```
en-GB.mod_latesttweets.ini
en-GB.mod_latesttweets.sys.ini
```

Inside language file like below.

```
MOD_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "Consumer Key"
```

Then Joomla will place this file in the proper language folder while you install the module.
Once you have installed the module and needs to change the language labels. Should be change inside Joomla language folder file.

You can download a sample module from this [link](http://www.walkswithme.net/latest-tweets-joomla-module) and check the structure.

The issue look like your language file does not exists.

Hope its helps..

Comment: I have the language file INSIDE the module folder. It has no issues when I first install the module. It only fails when I update the language file. I'm not sure if I have to reinstall the module after every update made to the language file. Also see my new comment above.

Comment: check the path languages/en-GB/your_mod.ini (module name) also make sure once you install module the language file changes should be in the above path.